# C# EasyModbusTCP.NET communication with keyence PLC

Tags: c#, plc

So i need to communicate with a Keyence PLC via serial port and want to at least run the PLC via a C# application, i came across with EasyModBusTCP.net library and using the code below i manage to connect the PLC to my application but cannot manage to change the state of the PLC from "Stop" to "Run" using the application, don't know if the easyModbus is the correct library for this type of PLC's (KV-60)

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {

                ModbusClient modbusClient = new ModbusClient("COM8");
                modbusClient.UnitIdentifier = 1; //Not necessary since default slaveID = 1;
                modbusClient.Baudrate = 115200; // Not necessary since default baudrate = 9600
                modbusClient.Parity = System.IO.Ports.Parity.None;
                modbusClient.StopBits = System.IO.Ports.StopBits.Two;
                modbusClient.ConnectionTimeout = 500;           
                modbusClient.Connect();
                modbusClient.UDPFlag = true;
                label1.Text = "Online";
                //modbusClient.WriteSingleCoil(203, true);
                //modbusClient.WriteSingleRegister(000, 300);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                label1.Text = ex.Message.ToString();
                throw;
            }



        }
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "run" the PLC? Change the state of it from Stop to Run? Program it? Can you add a link to your PLC?

Comment: Yes change the state from stop to Run here is the link https://www.keyence.com.sg/products/controls/plc-terminal-block-type/kv_nano/models/kv-n60at/index.jsp

Answer (score 1):

The code you show above is just half of what you need to accomplish your goal.

To be able to switch the PLC state you need to write a routine in its software such that when you write a certain Modbus coil (which is no more than an address in its memory) it triggers that state change. That should not be difficult at all but you need to do it in the PLC itself.

Once you have implemented that you can use your code above, one of the lines you have commented should be enough:

```
modbusClient.WriteSingleCoil(run_stop, true); // True to run, False to stop
```

Where `run_stop` is the Modbus address you used in the PLC.

Once you figure out what language you want to use to program your PLC (you have several choices) and play around with it you can refocus your question or write a new one.